# Are SuiteBundle's and SuiteApp's the same thing?

Tags: netsuite

For example, I can see the Contra Account Sheet SuiteApp has been installed in my NetSuite account, but I cannot see it in the list of installed SuiteBundle's.

Is there somewhere else I need to go to view the list of SuiteApp's that I have installed in my NetSuite account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are not the same.  You can find the list of Installed SuiteApps by going to Customization > SuiteCloud Development > Installed SuiteApp List.  Alternatively, you can use the Global Search bar - enter "page: installed suiteapp list" and select the result shown.

Comment: "SuiteBundle and SuiteApp are the same thing and we use the term interchangeably" https://www.netsuite.eu/platform/developer/suitebundler.shtml

Comment: @PaulDraper: they are developed differently, provisioned differently and are found in different parts of the NetSuite navigation.  Judging by the screenshot image in that page you linked, I'd posit that it's rather old information, and probably from before SuiteApp had its own meaning within the NetSuite ecosystem.

Comment: I can believe that.